# UnicodeDecodeError, utf-8 invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.5

I m trying to extract lines from a log file , using that code :

```
    with open('fichier.01') as f:
         content = f.readlines()

    print (content)
```

but its always makes the error statement

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./parsepy", line 4, in <module>
    content = f.readlines()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2213: invalid continuation byte
```

how can i fix it ??

Comment: How is your file encoded?

Comment: It might help if you indicated the contents of bytes, say, 2212 to 2219.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's not encoded as text then you will have to open it in binary mode e.g.:

```
with open('fichier.01', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

If it's encoded as something other than UTF-8 and it can be opened in text mode then `open` takes an `encoding` argument: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open

Comment: thanks it's worked , its as you said , i added the 'rb' in the open function

Answer (score 12):

try one of the following

```
open('fichier.01', 'rb')
open('fichier.01', encoding ='utf-8')
open('fichier.01', encoding ='ISO-8859-1')
```

or also you can use [io Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open):

```
import io
io.open('fichier.01')
```

This is a common error when opening files when using Python (or any language really). This is an error you will soon learn to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it to solve it:

```
with open('fichier.01', errors='ignore') as f:
   ###
```