# Python read and write 'ß' from file

Tags: python, unicode

I have a file.txt with the input

```
Straße
Straße 1
Straße 2
```

I want to read this text from file and print it. I tried this, but it won´t work.

```
lmao1 = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()
lmao =random.choice(lmao1)
print str(lmao).decode('utf8')
```

But I get the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 5: invalid continuation byte

Comment: have you tried without `.decode('utf8')`? And yes, you can't decode strings, only encode them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309044/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-invalid-continuation-byte

Comment: without `.decode('utf8')` I get an output like `Stra▀e`

Comment: The type of `lmao` is `str` already. Why do you use `str` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. If this doesn't work try other common encodings until you find the right one. utf-8 is not the correct encoding.

```
print str(lmao).decode('latin-1')
```

Comment: No problem. Please mark this as the chosen answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows, the file is likely encoded in `cp1252`.

Whatever the encoding, use `io.open` and specify the encoding.  This code will work in both Python 2 and 3.

`io.open` will return Unicode strings.  It is good practice to immediately convert to/from Unicode at the I/O boundaries of your program.  In this case that means reading the file as Unicode in the first place and leaving `print` to determine the appropriate encoding for the terminal.

Also recommended is to switch to Python 3 where Unicode handling is greatly improved.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import io
import random
with io.open('file.txt',encoding='cp1252') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
line = random.choice(lines)
print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, regarding `decode`, the problem is only there is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/determine-the-encoding-of-text-in-python) to guess the encoding of a file 100%. Try a different encoding (e.g. `latin-1`).

Answer (score -1):

It's working fine on Python prompt and while running from python script as well.

```
>>> import random
>>> lmao =random.choice(lmao1)
>>> lmao =random.choice(lmao1)
>>> print str(lmao).decode('utf8')
Straße 2
```

The above worked on Python 2.7. May I know your python version ?

Comment: I use python 2.7 aswell. Can u post python script aswell, maybe i have just a mistake in it.

Comment: `import random

lmao1 = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()
lmao =random.choice(lmao1)
print str(lmao).decode('utf8')`