# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 5906: invalid continuation byte for unzipped file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting an error from my script about the encoding, but the file has been unzipped prior to running the script on it.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position
> 5906: invalid continuation byte for unzipped file

Does anyone know if there are characters that could be confusing the script and how to look at the position that this error is mentioning (is it a line in the file or the character position)?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to change the encoding, `latin-1` or `ISO-8859-1`. Something like `open('filename', encoding="ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: but there is no encoding. the file isn't zipped.

Comment: I think there may be a character somewhere in the file that's making it think it's compressed. I'm just not sure how to find it in the big file.

Comment: As can be seen from the error message, python is trying to read the file using `utf-8`codec. Try to change the encoding first. Sample code is provided on my first comment.

Comment: For further reading of similar issue and potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309044/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-invalid-continuation-byte

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the vim text editor, `:goto 5906` will take you to that position in the file.